# Android NDK - Unable to use jstring, keeps crashing

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I've spent my last two days on an JNI issue and it's driving me crazy...
I just try to do:

```
  SWIGEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_my_package_CM_1CoreJNI_CM_1Property_1name_1set(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jstring jarg2) {
    const char *arg2 = (*jenv)->GetStringUTFChars(jenv, jarg2, 0);
    ....
}
```

I'm calling this function through a JAR and it keeps crashing.
All that I can read from my LogCat is:

```
03-27 12:44:29.162: E/dalvikvm(1599): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale weak global reference 0x4080f657 (index 15765 in a table of size 0)
03-27 12:44:29.172: W/dalvikvm(1599): JNI WARNING: jstring is an invalid weak global reference (0x4080f657)
03-27 12:44:29.172: W/dalvikvm(1599):              in Lcom/my/package/CM_CoreJNI;.CM_Property_name_set:(JLjava/lang/String;)V (GetStringUTFChars)
```

After long investigations, I've tried to call that function directly from my activity (by adding native void set...) and worked fine!
I'm blocked and don't know how to do...

Did any one managed to call JNI from JAR successful?

EDIT: fixed by removing the jar and and adding the .java files...